# Firebase CSS media query not being applied

Tags: css, firebase, devops

Accessing my personal site with my own domain [removed] the css media query doesn't get applied. However, from firebases own generated url [removed] it works fine. I can't figure out what's going on here. Is it a caching issue?

Any help appreciated; thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my client the sites are identical, so it is probably caching isue on your side.